# Plotting cone of influence in Morlet wavelet power spectrum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I tried generating the cone of influence for a Morlet wavelet power spectrum using the following MATLAB code:

```
 cone = conofinf('morl',1:365,LenSig,[],'plot');
```

However, all I get is a strange looking shaded area bounded by two linear lines. It doesn't look like a cone of influence for Morlet wavelet power spectrum.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sorry,  around here we only know how to deal with The Cone of Silence

Comment: I wanted to upload an image showing the figure output on my post, but I didn't have enough reputation points to do so. I have uploaded the output at http://postimg.org/image/jhc1bnzf3/ if this is helpful. It appears that the linear lines are part of some y-intercepts of the cone of influence.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to output COI at the borders of your wavelet transform. In this case you have to specify the last parameter as non-empty vector, but with coordinates, where you need COI to be computed, e.g.

`cone = conofinf('morl',1:365,LenSig,[1 LenSig],'plot');`

I had a similar task and here's what I did:

```
figure;

% plot wavelet transform / scalogram
imagesc(t,scales,WT);
axis square;
colorbar;

% annotate axes and title
title('Coefficients of continuous wavelet transform');
xlabel('Time (or space) b'); 
ylabel('Scales a');

% get cone of influence
% Here, you have to specify points at which you want to calculate COI
% as the last parameter:
cone = conofinf(wname,scales,LenSig,[1 LenSig]);
% combine left and right edges
cone = [cone{1}(:,floor(1:LenSig/2)) cone{2}(:,ceil(LenSig/2):end)];
% previous steps give you an area under COI
% you can see it with: figure; imagesc(cone);
% now, we want to get the border of this area
coi  = zeros(1,LenSig);
for idx = 1:LenSig
    valcoi = find(cone(:,idx)==1,1,'last');
    if ~isempty(valcoi)
        coi(idx) = f(valcoi);
    end
end
% now plot COI border on top of your wavelet transform
hold on;
plot(t,coi,'k','LineWidth',1.5);
hold off;
```

Optionally, you can hatch the area under COI, but it's a bit of a hack and it's not ideal. For this you will need [hatchfill function](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30733-hatchfill) (here's an [example](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/) how to use it). Once you have this function on your path, you can use it like this:

```
[~,h] = contourf(t,scales,cone*max(WT(:)),[1 1]*max(WT(:)));
hPatch = findobj(h, 'Type', 'patch');
hh = hatchfill(hPatch, 'cross', 45, 10);
```